# data-tooltip not working when dragging in safari

Tags: javascript

When dragging this element:

```html
<a ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="name " id="X'5CF4E903CDEA5DBA0003D41B000000000000000000000000'" style="color:#000000" href="/link"><span onmouseout="closeMessage1();" onmouseover="delay1(event,'someText')" class="bold">Firstname, Lastname</span></a>
```

Over this element:

```html
<a data-tooltip="16:30" onclick="return confirm('Du er ved at booke en gammel tid i kalenderen. Ønsker du at fortsætte?')" href="/link"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="/Cam/Images/Spacer.gif"></a>
```

The `data-tooltip` doesn't show up despite the fact that the cursor is changing to a hand cursor as expected. It works fine when not dragging in safari. It works fine in firefox, chrome and edge when dragging.

I've tried:

```
aElement.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown(event), false);

function mouseDown(event){
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

For some weird reason the `data-tooltip` works in safari after either command, option, control or fn key is pressed on mac keyboard.

```
function dragStart(event) {
            draggedElement.style.position = "fixed";
            draggedElement.style.zIndex = "1";

if(!is_safari){
                event.preventDefault();
            }else{
event.preventDefault();
                therapistDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown(event), false);
            }
            iDiv.setAttribute("style","height:"+therapistDiv.clientHeight+"px;");
            var rect = therapistDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
            offset = [
                therapistDiv.offsetLeft  - rect.left,
                therapistDiv.offsetTop  - rect.top
            ];
            isDown = true;
        }

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
if(isDown){
 dropBooking(element);
 isDown = false;
}

}, true);

function dropBooking(div) {
 form.submit();
}
```

chrome `data-tooltip` working fine when dragging. But the little tooltip "15:30" doesn't show up in safari when dragging and the mouse is pressed. It only works after either shift, fn, control, option or command is pressed.
[image]